# SQL Server 2005 - Copy differences in tables only

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, sql-server-2005, database-backups

I've had an issue with a SQL Server database after an update from some horrible software. The software "updated" (in actuality, rolled-back) a bunch of encrypted stored procedures and user-defined functions in the database, which is now causing errors in other software.

Thankfully I took a backup from just before the update, however the error wasn't noticed until about an hour later which means records have been updated/inserted/deleted etc since the backup was taken.

Originally my idea was to simply copy the stored procedures and functions to a new database created from the backup, then backup and restore this database onto the broken database, but as they are encrypted I can't copy them.

So the next idea was to transfer the tables from the broken database to the restored database and proceed as above. However I run in to several issues with the existing tables, such as the DBTimeStamp column not allowing the copy.  However copying the tables to new clean database works fine.

So here are the questions:

1. What's the best way to effectively merge the tables from the backup with the tables from the broken db?
2. Would simply truncating or dropping the existing tables in the backup avoid these validation errors?  I get error messages like "VS_ISBROKEN" etc when trying to use the export data function to push the data across, with dropping the existing data set and Identity_Insert turned on etc. (Truncating)

I have yet to try dropping all the tables on the backup and going from there.  Would there be an adverse effect with Metadata if I approached the problem this way?

I feel like this should be quite simple, and had the provider not locked down all the functions and stored procedures I wouldn't need to copy the tables out like this.

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: There are several data compare tools on the market, you should try them out.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've looked into a couple (ApexSQL and LiteSpeed) but I didn't really want to install trial software on the server just for this one task.  There should be a way to just script this out with native SQL, my next attempt will be to just use the "SELECT * FROM INTO" on each table, but that's time consuming to run on each individual table.

Comment: You don't have to install it on the server, just any workstation or even a VM that can connect to both databases. You can, of course, script this out for each table and do the compare yourself, but there is no magic button for that and this is really tedious work. This is why vendors make tools, precisely to make the work easier and so you can avoid all the bugs and data type nuances they've conquered over time. See https://thebertrandfamily.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-the-cost-of-reinventing-the-wheel/

Comment: @AaronBertrand If I could +1 that I would, thanks :)